# How to loop through nested JSON objects in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am working on a C# project where I need to call an API and parse through the JSON response.

The JSON response:

```
{
    "version": "3.9.1",
     "data": {
        "obj1": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "id": "obj1",
            "name": "Object 1",
            "title": "Object 1",
            "info": {
                "info1": 8,
                "info2": 4,
                "info3": 3
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Object1.png",
                "w": 64,
                "h": 64
            },
            "tags": [
                "Tag1",
                "Tag2"
            ]
        },
        "obj2": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "id": "obj2",
            "name": "Object 2",
            "title": "Object 2",
            "info": {
                "info1": 1,
                "info2": 6,
                "info3": 7
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Object2.png",
                "w": 64,
                "h": 64
            },
            "tags": [
                "Tag1",
                "Tag6"
            ]
        },
        "obj3": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "id": "obj3",
            "name": "Object 3",
            "title": "Object 3",
            "info": {
                "info1": 0,
                "info2": 1,
                "info3": 2
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Object3.png",
                "w": 64,
                "h": 64
            },
            "tags": [
                "Tag7",
                "Tag8"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

With this response, I want to loop through all the objects located inside `data`. The number of objects inside `data` isn't always the same; it is possible that there will only be one object or ten objects.

The problem I ran into is that I can't loop through the `data` property because of the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Objects' because 'Objects' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I know why I am getting the error, but I can't find a way of fixing my problem.

My code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(path);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string ReaderJson = reader.ReadToEnd();

var JsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(ReaderJson);

foreach (var obj in JsonResponse.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}
```

**JsonParser.cs**

```
    public class Response
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public Objects data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Objects
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Info info { get; set; }
        public Images images { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public int info1 { get; set; }
        public int info2 { get; set; }
        public int info3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Images
    {
        public string full { get; set; }
        public int w { get; set; }
        public int h { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I loop through all the objects inside `data` without calling them using `obj1`, `obj2`, etc.?

Comment: I'm guessing that data is not what you're thinking it is. It looks like data is an object, not a collection.

Comment: Your data model doesn't map to your JSON data. Your `data` property should be a `Dictionary<string, Objects>`. (As an aside, the class name `Objects` is a bit peculiar here; only collections should be named as plurals.)

Comment: ahh alright thanks! and yes I wanted to rename the Objects class afterwards but I first wanted to fix this problem. Just a bad practice that I sadly enough do quite often.

Comment: FYI: I formalized that comment as an answer with a bit more detail—though it sounds like you already got the main points from my comment. Let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your JSON schema defines a ***dictionary*** for `data`, but your `data` *property* returns a ***single instance*** of your `Objects` class.

#### Data Model

What you want is for your `Response` class to look something like this:

```cs
public class Response
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Objects> data { get; set; }
}
```

Everything else should be fine.

#### Looping Through Data

Given the above, you can now loop through the `data` dictionary using something like:

```cs
foreach (var obj in JsonResponse.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
}
```

> *Note:* When looping through a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, an enumeration of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`s will be returned, with your key (i.e., `obj1`) in the `Key` property, and your object in the `Value` property.

#### Naming Conventions

Obviously, the name `Objects` doesn't makes sense here, since it represents a single object, not a collection of objects. I'm keeping it `Objects` for consistency with your code, but you'll want to give it a singular name. I assume that was just left over from you wanting it to represent a collection.

Comment: @MrMilkshake: Glad to hear! As an aside, if you control the data, an alternative approach would be to treat `data` as an array in your JSON, and then map it to a `Collection<>`—or, if you still want it to be keyed, then a `KeyedCollection<>` based on your `id` property.

Comment: Yeah it would be alot easier if data was indeed a array but sadly enough the JSON comes as a response from an API and I am not able to change it :( but the `KeyedCollection<>` is a great alternative i'll give it a try :D